# GitHub 'push branch to server' button does what?

Tags: github

I pulled down the master branch of one of our GitHub repos (did not fork it) and branched from the command line, did some work, added + committed and then rebased master.

When I called `git push` from the command line I got a message stating `The current branch has no upstream branch.  To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin my_branch.`

Well, I saw the mention in there of 'origin' and was a little worried this would somehow push my changes to master and not `my_branch`.  I'm new to GitHub and thought I should play it safe.

Instead, I opened the GitHub for windows client, found my branch in there and clicked the 'push branch to server' button.  (At least I think that's what it said.)  Lo and behold, it worked.

What did clicking that button do behind the scenes, so I know which commands to run the next time through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like the command mentioned - `git push origin my_branch`.

The message `The current branch has no upstream branch.` means that Git cannot find a remote branch associated with your newly created branch (that makes sense, there's no such branch in the remote repository).

`git push --set-upstream origin my_branch` means "take the local my_branch, find my_branch in origin and upload the changes there. Also set origin/my_branch as the default branch for git push in my_branch". So the next time, with my_branch checked out, you simply `git push` and the changes are uploaded to the appropriate remote branch.

`man git push` has some good and demonstrative examples (as well as other git commands).

Comment: Thank you.  If `my_branch` doesn't exist in origin, is it safe to assume it will create it there?  (Say for instance, if I pulled from origin and made a local branch?)

Comment: @larryq: Yes, it is. If you don't specify a remote branch, git (creates and) uploads to the remote branch with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It basically did:

```
git checkout my_branch
git push origin my_branch
```

If you do

```
git push --set-upstream origin my_branch
```

Everytime you are in the branch, all you will need to do is run:

```
git push
```

And it will automatically go to `my_branch` branch on Github.